# Multiple Data And [Object] [Object]

Tags: angular

I use mongoDB, express, angular , nodejs

i have a 2 problems:

1) when I get the data from http 
i get to the subscribe function in the component [Object][Object]

2) I think that i have problem with the subscribe and the unsbscribe 
    becuase I get in the start what i need to get but after when i do 
    something I get Multiple data 
    for example: if I have 2 pic of apple and banana After that it will be
     apple banana apple banana 
     I want to see only 1 apple and 1 banana

#### component.component.ts

```
export class MealMenusComponent implements OnInit,  OnDestroy {
menu: Menu[] = [];



ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.mlService.getMeal().subscribe(res  => {
     this.menu = res;
     console.log(this.menu);  ----------->> [Object][Object]
  });


ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


}
```

#### service.service.ts

```
  public getMeal() {
  return  this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/meals')
    .pipe(
      map(responseData => {
        for (const key in responseData) {
          if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.menu.push({ ...responseData[key]});   /
          }
        }
        console.log(this.menu); ----------->> print the data correctly
        return this.menu;

      })
    );
```

#### menu.module.ts

```
export class Menu {

  public name: string;
  public description: string;
  public imagePathFront: string;
  public imagePathBack: string;
  public category: string;
  public price: number;


  constructor(name: string, description: string, imagePathFront: string, imagePathBack: string, category: string, price: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.imagePathFront = imagePathFront;
    this.imagePathBack = imagePathBack;
    this.category = category;
    this.price = price;
  }
```

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.menu));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your getting that because you are trying to console log an array of objects. you can loop through each one and print individually or do something like `console.log(this.menu[0].name)`

2) The http get call( if you are using HttpClient ) should already be giving you an array of objects, which you can then assign to your `menu: Menu[]` variable in your subscribe callback. Like so.

**in your service.**

```
public getMeal() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/meals');
}
```

**in your component**

```
this.mlService.getMeal().subscribe(menuItems => this.menu = menuItems);
```

then in your html you can loop through the properties of each menu item like so

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of menu">
 <li> {{ item.name }} </li>
 <li> {{ item.description}} </li>
 ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Double data:**

I would guess the reason for the duplication of the data is, that you always push the new results to the menu array in your getMeal function in the service. You should think about resetting the menu array before you add new keys (just before the for loop).

```
this.menu = [];
```

**[object][object]**

with this line

```
this.menu.push({ ...responseData[key]});
```

you add an object to the menu array using the spread operator. Without knowing the structure of you response data this seems kind of weired to me, but it might result in what you are seeing when logging it to the console. So if you want to change someting in the result of this.menu, you should change the above mentioned line.

Some examples of the result data could help here.